# Moving large number of large files in git repository

Tags: git, rename, mv, large-data

My repository has large number of large files.
They are mostly data (text).
Sometimes, I need to move these files to another location due to refactoring or packaging.

I use `git mv` command to "rename" the path of the files, but it seems inefficient in that the size of the commit (the actual diff size) is very huge, same as `rm`, `git add`

Is there other ways to reduce the commit size?
or should I just add them to `.gitignore` and upload as a zip file to upstream?

---

Thank you for the answers.

FYI,
following series of commands will result the size of the file `bar`

```
git mv foo bar
git commit -m "modify"
git cat-file -s HEAD:bar
```

from which I thought git did `rm` and `add`.
Would you tell me if this info is not related to the actual size or not?

Comment: What do you mean with "commit size"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By design, if you move a file inside a Git repository without changing content, creating a commit will only store new metadata (a.k.a. tree objects) to represent new file location. 
Since content is unchanged, Git doesn't need to create new blob object to store file content.
So "commit size" should be rather small.

Since you say that diff size is huge, I suppose that some file content is modified along with relocation. This would be a reason for "commit size" to be huge.

In both case, you can try to shrink .git directory size with the command `git gc --prune --aggressive`

**EDIT :**

```
git mv foo bar
git commit -m "modify"
git cat-file -s HEAD:bar
```

These commands create a new commit, but the since the foo/bar file content has not changed, Git won't store anything new but the new file name. In fact, in you example, `git cat-file -s HEAD:foo` before rename and `git cat-file -s HEAD:bar` after will give you the same result, since its the same content (same blob in .git/objects).
I think you are mis-interpreting things that git does internally. Have a look to [Git objets](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) to get further explanations.

Remember that git tracks content, not files.

Answer (score 2):

Moving things around in git does not change the size of the repository. Each file is stored exactly once in the repository. You will only increase the size of the repository if you start to change those huge files. - Then each new version is stored separately.

Have a look at [git-annex](http://git-annex.branchable.com/), maybe that is the right thing for you.

Comment: This did not happened to me. I renamed some directories, which contained image files. git marked them as renamed, during git push I had to wait for the upload to finish and the repository size has increased with 600 MB (which is the size of the image files)